# Foundation (3) Orbit Image Slider

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have the following code for an image slider in Foundation 3.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
         <div id="slider">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x375&text=[img 1]" />
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x375&text=[img 2]" />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, at the end of the file I have the following js in order for it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
     $('#slider').orbit();
 }); </script>
```

When I load the page for a little time both images appear stacked until it loads into the Orbit Slider. **I really would like to minimize this and not have the images appear until the slider is loaded.** I have a very fast VPS setup and something like this has never really been a problem. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to change the visibility of the `<div id="slider"></div>`with javascript inside a document.ready function to visible:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slider').toggle();
    $('#slider').orbit();
});
```

This of course means you have to specify that the `display` is `none` in the css document:

```
#slider {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for the tip! It seems to be working; however, the images are not appearing. http://tinyurl.com/bscr6fa

Answer (score 1):

Just add to `<div id="slider"></div>` height and overflow:hidden

```
#slider {
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}